# The ViewData item that has the key 'Name' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I am doing an application where the users register themselves. I have problem with my dropdowlist.When I want to create my user with his Role, I have the Title's problem. My code is this:

`----Register.cshtml----`

`<!--Select the Role Type for the User-->
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Select Your User Type", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Name")
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Ends Here-->`

`----AccountController.cs----`

```
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(),"Name","Name");
        return View();
    }


    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                //Assign Role to user Here 
                await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Name);
                //Ends Here


                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    //
```

`RoleController.cs`

```
public class RoleController : Controller
{
    ApplicationDbContext context;

    public RoleController()
    {
         context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Get All Roles
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Roles = context.Roles.ToList();
        return View(Roles);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create  a New role
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var Role = new IdentityRole();
        return View(Role);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a New Role
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Role"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(IdentityRole Role)
    {
        context.Roles.Add(Role);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


}
```

I want to know why I can't create my user with his role.

Comment: Well, simply put, your problem is that the ViewData item that has the key 'Name' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: @Blogbeard, I thought the same thing and posted and answer along those lines.  Jorge says that answer did not work, so I deleted it.  I've carefully read over his code (only the first two source files posted are necessary), and he's got a `ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(),"Name","Name");`, so he's not setting his ViewBag item to a string.

Comment: Finally with ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(),"Name","Name"); everything works.

Comment: because the relation is many to many :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075578/correct-way-of-setting-the-role-for-user-when-he-is-registered-with-identity